# Programatically pull user data based on "Likes" and "Check Ins"

Tags: windows, automation, facebook-like, checkin, reward

Is it possible to programmatically pull all the users that Liked your business page so a business could reward them?  From what I am reading it doesn’t appear possible but I see advertisements where businesses are saying they can do it.

**Details:**

I would like to build an application to allow my customers ( businesses ) to give their customers that **Liked** their page or **Checked In** to thier business something extra to their account.

Example:

- Customer L *Liked my page*
- Customer C *Checked In at my business*
- Customer X *did neither*

**Program Queries Facebook’s Data...**

- Finds Customer L and adds a 10% off to Customer L’s next purchase
- Finds Customer C and adds a free drink to the Customers Next visit
- Customer X gets no freebies but is still my customer

I have done 0 programming with the Facebook API but am a developer, just not sure if what I want to do is possible.  If it is possible just need to have an idea where to start.

Thanks!

**Added As a Response**

Thanks for the prompt response!

My background is mostly web development in .Net ( mostly VB.Net ), JavaScript and HTML.

I need to make this program run independently of the web ( as a stand-alone app ) so C# sounds like a good solution.  I didn’t see that as an option when looking at the SDKs but I have only been researching this for a couple of days.
I looked over the examples that you sent and here is my questions after looking over what you sent:
My customers ( businesses ) already have their pages setup and also already have people that have liked them.  We may have “an” email address ( may not match the one used for FB ), name, phone number birthdate and address.  It looks like using the first method you sent me ( modified to look at Coca-Cola’s Likes ) https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/likes/ that I may be able to walk the list of all users that Like this page.  Now I ran this on one of my pages I created yesterday that does have 1 Like ( me testing it ) and I get:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

- My question is with the information we have on the actual customer,
  what is the best reliable method for matching that to Likes on FB?
- Do my customers have to go rebuild their pages and have users
  “reLike” them and add the "request permissions" in order to get that data?
- Also is there an alerting feature that will give me the data when a
  user Likes a page versus me having to pull it ( trying to conserve
  bandwidth on Facebook’s side ) multiple times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What type of developer are you? You first have to decide which API you are going to use: JavaScript, PHP, C#...

[Here is an example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/18/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-pull-the-movies-friends-like/) of how to get the likes of movies as one example of getting likes.
Here is an example post to open graph to see if a user likes a page: https://graph.facebook.com/USERID YOU ARE INTERESTED IN/likes/PAGE ID
If that user likes that page, it will return a result. If not, the result will be empty. You can test this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/likes/350165041668215), change out USER ID for some user's specific ID or put: me to represent yourself, and then plug in the id of your business page and see the result.

Comment: Added a second section to the question as a response.  Thanks.